# Xcode 7: Shadow does NOT show around UIView in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I want to see my UIView with added shadow like the example image below in storyboard. Unfortunately, there isn't an existing option to set it. Is there a way to set up the shadow using keypath so I can view the shadow in storyboard?

**EDIT:**

I have tried to render a shadow with the following code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable

class ShadowedView: UIView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0.5)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        self.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath
        self.clipsToBounds = false

    }
}
```

`@IBDesignable` allowed me to see the changes immediately, but the shadow still is not present in the storyboard. Here is a screenshot of it:[image: this]

And the result should be the example image. Thank you!

Image credit to [@Wezly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/757214/wezly)

[image: example of shadow]

Answer (score 1):

You would need to override `drawRect:` or `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` depending on your needs. You can read more in the docs : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/Chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html

Bottom line : you will have to add the code you posted in the `drawRect:` method in your custom view annotated as `IBDesignable` and Interface Builder will render it for you.

Comment: hi. i have tried both `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` and `drawRect` functions, but to no avail. Does IB allow shadow to be displayed at design time?

Comment: Well, from what I tried in the meantime I managed to display shadow, but only when I also rounded the corners. If you are still interested I can post the code.

Comment: same. but my view isnt with rounded corners unfortunately. I suppose it is a bug then if it displays in one state but not the other?

Comment: Maybe. To be honest, I haven't checked if there is a radar filed for it. If not, it may be worth filing one, even if to just learn that it is not supperted by choice.